# Заполнить массив случайными неубывающими числами

Tags: java, массивы

Как создать массив и заполнить его положительными числами, чтобы они образовывали неубывающую последовательность( каждый элемент не меньше предыдущего).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте разбить Вашу задачу на простые шаги:

1. Создать массив чисел (каких чисел?) заданного размера.
2. Сгенерировать положительное случайное число.
3. Записать это число в массив.
4. Повторить 2 и 3 для всех элементов массива.
5. Отсортировать массив.

Comment: Достойный ответ! Провести декомпозицию, не оказывая медвежьих услуг с готовым кодом, - это педагогично)

Answer (score 0):

Пример неубывающего массива из 100 чисел в диапазоне 10-1000:

```
int[] ints = new Random().ints(100, 10, 1000).sorted().toArray();
```

Comment: Если без стримов, то я бы начал в цикле заполнять массив с какого-то начального числа (можно выбрать тоже рандомно) и как разность между текущим и следующим числом выбирать рандомное из определенного диапазона... Как-то так

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[100];
        array[0] = (int) (0 + Math.random() * 101);
        for (int i = 1 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
                array[i] = (int) (array[i-1] + Math.random() * ((array[i-1]+100) - array[i-1] + 1));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```